# Do I need to do a heavy migration to modify relationships in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data, migration

My app loads user info from my backend and then attempts to save everything using core data. I have a couple of entities, and some one to many relationships in my data model. My question is, if the data changes in my database, and I need to modify the relationships between entities, for example add/delete, do I need to do a heavy migration? I have searched and read a lot online, it seems like lightweight migration is not gonna do it because I'm not manually adding attributes/entities. And if I do need to do a heavy migration, how would one go about that? There is really not too much I could find about heavy migration out there.

I also thought of just deleting previous data models every time I make a change then save the entire new entity. I'm not so sure if that is a good approach, is there a better way to cache/store data that's retrieved from backend?

Comment: May I ask (silly question) what do you mean with the backend, normally Coredata handles by itself the communication between the data storage (database, xml, file) and the View so before I make more comments I need to understand if you are not duplication functionality (like using core data and at the same time using a manually created sqlite file).

Comment: I'm using Parse as my backend, so basically every time I made a query to Parse and get the data i need, I want to store it using Core Data that way I dont have to keep making random queries each time a page is presented.

Comment: Do you want to change the data model or do you want to change the data?

Comment: I want to change the data, the data model stays the same, meaning that all relationships and attributes stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have done this but in case you haven't, when you change the model you need to save as a new version then select that one as current version with that the error should go away.

Here are the steps:

1. Select Model.xcdatamodeld.
2. Click Editor > Add Model Version....
3. Click Finish to accept Model 2 as the version name.
4. Select Model.xcdatamodeld.
5. Click View > Utilities > Show File Inspector (or press Option+⌘+1).
6. Set the Current Model Version to Model 2.

Here a link with explains this process:
[Learning CoreData for iOS: Managed Object Model Migration](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2150667&seqNum=2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not changing the model you need **no** migration.

That is, "migration" in the sense that Apple uses it, i.e. only in reference to the data *model*. What you mean is perhaps a data "update".

You do data updates in the usual way: fetch the objects you want to modify, change them (e.g., set different objects as relationships), save.

Comment: It keeps throwing an error:  incompatibility with the original data store (something like that), I didn't change the data model so is this because I didn't subclass NSManagedObject for the attributes?

Comment: I am sure you *did*  change the data model. Easiest way is to delete the app from the device / simulator and run it again.